# Use redux store in web-worker

Tags: redux, middleware, web-worker

I use web-workers to separate heavy calculations from the main thread. Application's stack consists of `react` and `redux`. So `web-workers` are created as an object in a `redux middleware` using `webpack's` `worker-loader`. Application receives huge messages from the backend with a very high speed and each message is processed by that `web-worker`. For each messages corresponding action and the whole store are passed to `web-worker` via `postMessage`. 
`store` contains really huge objects and it is expensive action to pass it on every `postMessage`.
Is there any way to import or to pass `store` once to `web-worker`?

Comment: You can't share state across a web-worker boundary. Your going to have to listen the webworker 'onmessage' event. Inside the web-worker call 'postMessage' when the work is done and have the main thread respond appropriately during the onmessage event.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers